# CSS external sheet

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a webpage using a "central" CSS external sheet that is called by THREE HTML files. The problem that I have is to do with background color; each HTML file should have a different colour. I start off by adding the line

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="EuropeanCountries.css" />
```

within the  and  of my HTML file called "France.html". I add exactly the same line within the  and  of my other two HTML files called "Italy.html" and "Germany.html". I then add the line  inside "France.html" and  inside "Italy.html" and  inside "Germany.html". Then, I go to my css file called "EuropeanCountries.css" and I add the lines

```
   body#page1{background-color:rgb(255,0,0);}
   body#page2{background-color:rgb(0,255,0);}
   body#page3{background-color:rgb(0,0,255);}
```

I then save ALL the HTML files and css external sheet inside the same directory. I then try to open "France.html" with the Opera browser and the background color is WHITE, which is what it should NOT be. The background color for the other two HTML files are ALSO white! So something is wrong. When I link ONE HTML file with the css file, eg. "France.html" with "EuropeanCountries.css" (and there are no other HTML files in my directory), the background color works just fine. But when I try to link multiple files with one CSS file, things go awry. Can anyone please point out to me exactly where I've gone wrong?

Comment: In my maiden post above, it seems that not everything I wrote has been included in my post. I added the line body id="page1" (with triangular brackets) to my France.html file and body id="page2" to my Italy.html file and body id="page3" in my Germany.html file. I should get different background colours for each of my HTML files, but I'm not getting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according the css, your body should have tags:

```
<body id="page1">...</body>
```

etc,

but I'd go with

```
.red { background: red; }
.green { background: green; }
.blue { background: blue; }
```

and

```
<body class="red">...</body>
```

correspondingly